# Problems calling fullcalendar method

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fullcalendar

I'm trying to make FullCalendar more useful and I'm trying to build features like inserting events with it's complete API.

I have this function on dayClick event:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                var now = new Date();
                if (now < date){//Only allow create events in the future
                    var target = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
                    var url = 'views/events.php';
                    var data = url + '?date='+target;
                    $.fancybox(
                        {
                            'autoDimensions'    : false,
                            'type'              : 'iframe',
                            'href'              : data,
                            'width'                 : 700,
                            'height'                : 500,
                            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                            'onClosed'          : function(){
                                $.refetchEvents();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
```

The fancybox is called and so the onClosed function but it says always "is not a function"

I've tried with $.fullCalendar('refetchEvents') (as said in the API http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/) and $.fullCalendar.refetchEvents();

The only way it gives no errors is:

$.fullCalendar.refetchEvents;

But if I look at the Firebug console it doesn't refresh anything.

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you have lazyFetching turned off, this could be just caching the events and recalling them when you run refetchEvents

Comment: Nopes, this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I think you need to reference the calendar that you want to refresh, try this: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );

Comment: Now works! I thought that given the fact I was under this "selection" this should work. Please, post it as answer in order to choose it as valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$.refetchEvents();
```

To

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
```